# Is it possible set a windows bar?

Tags: desktop, pantheon, plank

Is it possible set a simple and light windows bar? ...below the dock or in another site (in taskbar)?

[image]

Comment: If you want that then try KDE.elementary OS is supposed to be like OS X

Answer (score 1):

## About install KDE or other DE

You can install KDE/GNOME on Elementary OS, but this isn't recommended, if you want use GNOME install Ubuntu, if you want use KDE install KUBUNTU etc.
Anyway, you can install KDE with this guide, works for Ubuntu and Elementary OS, [INSTALL KDE PLASMA 5.2 IN UBUNTU 14.04](https://itsfoss.com/install-kde-plasma-ubuntu-1410/)

## Alternative

You can put the bottom bar in Elementary OS without install other DE, you have to install `Enlightenment`, you can look this photo and watch the bottom bar.
[image]
You cao

Go on Log out.

Click your user and click the gear in top right in the box and select `Enlightenment`.

Enter your password.

Here you will have `Enlightenment`.
If you don't found option `Enlightenment` use this commands:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:enlightenment-git/ppa
>
> apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install e20

Answer (score 0):

you can try with tint2
https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/tint2/
is lightweight and simple